# Why [].constructor in [Array] returns false

Tags: javascript

Why using `in` construct here:

```
[].constructor in [Array]
```

returns `false`, although

```
[].constructor == Array
```

returns `true`

Comment: Have you found the solution you were looking for or waiting for other answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator checks if the key exists, not the value:

> it returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

```
'key' in ['key']
```

Will return `false`, while:

```
0 in ['key']
```

will return `true`

---

To check if the value exists you could use the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method:

```
[Array].includes([].constructor)
```

will return `true`

Answer (score 1):

The **in** operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain. not the value , it checks if the property for example in your array , the array has properties which is indexes (numbers) start from 0 
so if we return back to your example

if we check that the array has a prop  0 , it returns true , if we check it has a prop 1 it returns false because the array has only one element with index 
 0

```js
let arr = [Array] 
console.log(0 in arr ) ; // true 
console.log(1 in arr) ; // false
```

let's look at another example

```js
let obj = {
    constructorArray : Array
}
console.log('constructorArray' in obj);  // true 
console.log(obj.constructorArray === [].constructor) ; // true 
console.log(Array in obj) ; // false
```

learn more

[in operator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)